# How to restore removed Cpanel Symbol Link

Tags: linux, server, cpanel

I accidentally removed the following symbolic link:

```
rm: remove symbolic link `/scripts/restorepkg'? y
```

How can I restore this? 
Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the symlink the original file is unchanged , you can restore the symlink through `ln -s`:

```
ln -s /path/to/original/ /path/to/link
```

Comment: ¡Thank you very much!